# SingleChildScrollView still overflowing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a SingleChildScrollView inside of a Sized box. I thought this would make my page scrollable but it does not. I get this when I run it
[image: Overflow]

I have the code

```
Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: Column(
        children: [
            const SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: some text
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                            children: items
                                    .map((e) => ListTile(
                                                most recent items
                                            ))
                                    .toList(),
                        ),
                    )),
        ],
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need wrap your `SizedBox` with `Expanded`, so the `SingleChildScrollView` get available `height` in `column`, like this:

```
Expanded(
  child: SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        ...
      ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: @WilliamD47 was it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with

```
Expanded(
child :SizedBox(
child :...
)
)
```

or

```
SizedBox.expand(

)
```

or give the sized box screen dimensions

```
var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
var screenHieght = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

SizedBox(
width: screenWidth,
height: screenHeight
child : YOUR CHILD HERE,
)